# How to parse data field?

Tags: 7

I'm using Drupal 7.14 + [ulogin](http://www.ulogin.ru) module (for auth. through social networks) and have following records in the database:

```
# select uid,name,data from drupal_users where uid=20041;
  uid  |               name                |
                                             data

-------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
 20041 | ulogin_odnoklassniki_406011483750 | a:2:{s:7:"contact";i:1;s:6:"ulogin";a:8:{s:7:"network";s:13:"odnoklassniki";s:8:"identity";s:36:"http://odnoklassniki.ru/406011483750";s:3:"uid";s:12:"4060114
83750";s:10:"first_name";s:18:"\320\220\320\273\320\265\320\272\321\201\320\260\320\275\320\264\321\200";s:3:"sex";s:1:"2";s:5:"photo";s:70:"http://i506.odnoklassniki.ru/getImage?photoId=348908356448&pho
toType=4";s:4:"city";s:0:"";s:6:"manual";s:0:"";}}
(1 row)


# select * from drupal_ulogin_identity where uid=20041;
 id |  uid  |    network    |  ulogin_uid  |
                           data

----+-------+---------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------
  2 | 20041 | odnoklassniki | 406011483750 | a:8:{s:7:"network";s:13:"odnoklassniki";s:8:"identity";s:36:"http://odnoklassniki.ru/406011483750";s:3:"uid";s:12:"406011483750";s:10:"first_name";s:18:"\320\
220\320\273\320\265\320\272\321\201\320\260\320\275\320\264\321\200";s:3:"sex";s:1:"2";s:5:"photo";s:70:"http://i506.odnoklassniki.ru/getImage?photoId=348908356448&photoType=4";s:4:"city";s:0:"";s:6:"man
ual";s:0:"";}
(1 row)
```

My question is - how to decode the `data` column in PHP? It looks like JSON, but is not JSON. I understand that `a:2` is an array with 2 items and `s:18` is a 18-chars long string... but how to parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data column is a serialized php object. Take a look at the [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php) function.

Comment: Thank you, and how do I access that field (is it called "user tokens"?), if I have `function hook_block_view($block_name = '') { global $user;` ?

Answer (score 4):

As @lenni rightly says it's a serialized PHP variable. But `data` is a property of the user entity type so you don't actually need to unserialize it yourself.

When the user object is loaded from the database it's automatically populated with the unserialized version of the `data` column. So all you need to do to access your 'user tokens' field (if such a field exists, it doesn't appear to from your screenshot) is this:

```
global $user;
$user_tokens = $user->data['user tokens'];
```